# Python Subpackages not available for import

Tags: python, import

I'm working from the basis of this previously posted problem:
[module importing itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686684/module-importing-itself/20687094#20687094)

Essentially, that problem is solved, but in the "modulename.py" file, there is a class defined, with an init function, and a ui function. Inside the class, any line of the form:

```
import submodule
```

Will function just fine. However..

```
import submodule.subsubmodule
```

or

```
import subsubmodule
```

Will produce an ImportError.

All submodules and subsubmodules have an

```
__init__.py
```

file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This often happens if you have multiple modules with the same name inside a package.

For example, consider:

```
mypkg/
  __init__.py
  toplevel.py
  mypkg.py
```

If the `toplevel.py` file calls `import mypkg.mypkg`, it will actually be importing the `mypkg.py` file and *not* the package.

You can solve this by including `from __future__ import absolute_import` as the first line in `toplevel.py`, which will force it to import the top-level package.

Alternatively, you can use `from . import mypkg` in `toplevel.py`, which will explicitly import the `mypkg.py` file.

Comment: When I try a relative import, I get an error stating:  ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package # 
Why is this?
I'll try the absolute import as well in a moment.

Comment: Confusingly, the relative imports can only be used if the file they are being used from is being used as part of a package. For example, `python toplevel.py` and `python mypkg/toplevel.py` will *not* work because the file is being called directly. However, running `python` then `import mypkg.toplevel` *will* work because `toplevel.py` is being imported as part of a package.